# FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in angular application

Tags: angular-cli

I'm encountering an error when running the `ng build` command in my Angular application.

**environment setup:**

Angular/cli version: 15.0.3

Node.js version: 20

Any other suggestions instead of give more memory to node process using `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"` env

I upgraded to angular/cli version to 17.3.2 but it doesn't work